# Checking for multiple enum cases

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum with many cases, and several functions to check if a struct matches it.

Right now I do something like this:

```
public enum Type { 
    case A1
    case A2
    case A3
    case B1
    case B2
    case C1
    case C2
    case C3
    case C4
    case C5
    case C6
    //
}

struct myStruct {
    public var type: Type = .A1

    func isA() -> Bool {
       return (type == .A1 || type == .A2 || type == .A3)
    }
}
```

This works, but I was wondering if I could simplify that. I tried:

```
func isA() -> Bool {
   return (type == .A1 || .A2 || .A3)
}
```

But got a bunch of errors:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Type' to expected argument type 'Bool'

> Type 'Bool' has no member 'A1'

> Type 'Bool' has no member 'A2'

> Type 'Bool' has no member 'A3'

Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I missed that because I had “enum” in my searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably just check membership within a Set or Array:

```swift
public enum Type { 
    case A1
    case A2
    case A3
    // ...

    var isA: Bool { [.A1, .A2, .A3].contains(self) }
}
```

For completeness, you could also use pattern matching within a `switch` statement:

```swift
var isA: Bool {
    switch self {
        case .A1, .A2, .A3: return true
        default: return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn’t realize I could add that to the enum instead of the struct.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your enum have a type of Int, and don't override the default rawValue (which starts at zero and increments by one for each case) you can use inequalities to see if a given enum is in a range of other enums.

```
public enum Type: Int, CaseIterable { 
    case A1
    case A2
    case A3
    case B1
    case B2
    case C1
    case C2
    case C3
    case C4
    case C5
    case C6
    //
}


if let anEnum = Type.allCases.randomElement() {
    let lowest = Type.C1
    let highest = Type.C6
    let isInRange = anEnum.rawValue >= lowest.rawValue && anEnum.rawValue <= highest.rawValue
    let isInRangeString = isInRange ? "is" : "is not"
    print("enum \(anEnum) \(isInRangeString) in range \(lowest) to \(highest)")
}
```

(In the code above I also make `Type` conform to `CaseIterable` so I can use the computed property `allCases` to create a random item.)

If you want to test to see if an enum is in a arbitrary list of enum values, using set membership or a switch statement (as described by @Alexander) would be the way to go.